# How to $lookup with MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I perform a $lookup with the MongoDB C# driver? I cannot find it in their driver doc here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/

But if I understand this ticket in their JIRA correctly, it should be in the 2.2 version of the driver:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1374

Comment: I guess you are referring to a missing "helper" method, which should only be expected as most drivers implementing such things lag behind the features of new server releases. Aggregation pipelines as with normal queries are really just BSON structures. Anything you can construct as BSON Documents can be fed as input to either `.find()` or `.aggregate()`, just as long as it is valid. So just construct the pipeline directly as BSON documents. As long as you have a MongoDB 3.2 server to support `$lookup` of course. Which is the overriding factor here.

Comment: Note, that there are more complete examples than shown here at [Aggregate $lookup with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540059/2313887). Shows all the Queryable forms as well as the Fluent Builders of the driver.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use the AsQueryable() extension method on IMongoCollection<T>, you can then use the LINQ interface, as an example.

```
var query = from p in collection.AsQueryable()
            join o in otherCollection on p.Name equals o.Key into joined
            select new { p.Name, AgeSum: joined.Sum(x => x.Age) };
```

This was copied from the mongodb csharp driver documentation here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/linq/#lookup

Comment: What type is `otherCollection` ?

Comment: You need `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;` namespace to make this work

Comment: @tigrou `System.Linq` was enough for me

Answer (score 18):

You can also achieve that using the [collection.Aggregate().Lookup()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_AggregateFluentBase_1_Lookup__2.htm) method or by adding the lookup to the aggregate stages.

```
collection.Aggregate()
    .Lookup("foreignCollectionName", "localFieldName", "foreignFieldName", "result");
```

Comment: What about lookup with aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: @Homam A very detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530363/aggregate-lookup-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

**Problem is Lookup requires Projection**

```
Collection.Aggregate().Lookup("foreignCollectionName", "localFieldName", "foreignFieldName","result").Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
.ToList()
```

**Then You need it to convert to JSON**

```
String ConvertToJson= res[0].AsBsonDocument.ToJson();
String resultsConvertToJson = ConvertToJson.ToJson();
```

**Then use BSONSerialize and Put it in C# Strongly typed Collection**

```
List<TModel> results= BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TMModel>>(resultsConvertToJson);
```

Comment: can you explain if we can get result directly from you 1st part ? without convering to json

Answer (score 4):

**This worked for me:**

```
var collection2 = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("dbACESSO");

var match1 = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("PartnerId", cliente));
var match2 = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("CD_CLIENTE", codCond));

var lookup1 = new BsonDocument { { "$lookup", new BsonDocument { { "from", "GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "localField", "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "foreignField", "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "as", "GRUPO" } } } };

var pipeline = new[] { match1, match2, lookup1 };
var result = collection2.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

other than what the guys already mentioned, there is a type safe overload for the lookup method you can use.

Lookup is an extension method to your local collection, accepts 4 parameters, the first is the foreign collection, the second is an expression to your local field, the third is an expression to your foreign field, the fourth is an expression that map the result of the join to a field in your output type.

```
_fromTypeCollection.Aggregate<fromType>()
.Lookup<fromType,targetType,outputType>(targetTypeCollection,
fromType => fromType.localFeild, 
targetType => targetType.foreignField, 
outputType => outputType.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I agree @Shane 's answer, using the `IMongoQueryable<T>` interface is the least effort.

Nonetheless, you can use a typesafe lookup pipeline aswell, but you need two more models inheriting from the inner model.

Let's join pupils and their addresses. But first sample data:

**pupils**

```json
{ _id: { $oid: 0 }, name: "Homer Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
{ _id: { $oid: 1 }, name: "Marge Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
{ _id: { $oid: 2 }, name: "Ned Flanders", addressId: { $oid: 11 } },
```

**addresses**

```json
{ _id: { $oid: 10 }, address: "742 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield" },
{ _id: { $oid: 11 }, address: "740 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield" },
```

The pipeline first collects all `pupils` per address, then flattens the addresses and pupils into a list of n*1-1 relations.

```
db.adresses.aggregate([{
  $lookup:
  {
    from: "pupils",
      localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "addressId",
        as: "pupil",
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$pupil" },
])
```

`$lookup` stage produces a 1-n relation:

```json
{ _id: { $oid: 10 }, address: "742 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield", pupil:
  [
    { _id: { $oid: 0 }, name: "Homer Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
    { _id: { $oid: 1 }, name: "Marge Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
  ],
},
{ _id: { $oid: 11 }, address: "740 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield", pupil: 
  [
    { _id: { $oid: 2 }, name: "Ned Flanders", addressId: { $oid: 11 } },
  ],
},
```

`$unwind` flattens the pupil array, and "copies" the rest

```json
{ _id: { $oid: 10 }, address: "742 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield", pupil:
  { _id: { $oid: 0 }, name: "Homer Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
},
{ _id: { $oid: 10 }, address: "742 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield", pupil: 
  { _id: { $oid: 1 }, name: "Marge Simpson", addressId: { $oid: 10 } },
},
{ _id: { $oid: 11 }, address: "740 Evergreen Terrace", city: "Springfield", pupil:
  { _id: { $oid: 2 }, name: "Ned Flanders", addressId: { $oid: 11 } },
},
```

All in all we see 4 different models here

1. `Pupil := { name, addressId }`
2. `Address := { address, city }`
3. `AddressWithPupils := Address ∧ { pupil = {Pupil} }`
4. `AddressWithPupil := Addes ∧ { pupil = Pupil }`

Notice that the set of pupils is named `pupil` in 3 as well as the single `pupil` in 4. this is required due to the unwind stage unwinding the same field name.

```cs
record Pupil(ObjectId Id, string Name, ObjectId AddressId);
record Address(ObjectId Id, string Address, string City);
record AddressWithPupils(ObjectId Id, string Name, string City, IEnumerable<Pupil> Pupil) : Address(Id, Name, City);
record AddressWithPupil(ObjectId Id, string Name, string City, Pupil Pupil) : Address(Id, Name, City);
```

Now let's build our query with the C# driver.

```cs
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<Address>()
  .Lookup(_pupils, a => a.Id, p => p.AddressId, (AddressWithPupils as) => as.Pupil)
  .Unwind(as => as.Pupil, new AggregateUnwindOptions<AddressWithPupil>());
var adressWithPupilCursor = _address.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

We must aid the type inference at a few places to choose the correct models, like explicitly specifying the output type of the lookup stage as `AddressWithPupils` and the output type of the unwind stage as `AddressWithPupil`.

Other than that, this works.