# Mongodb Lookup with sorting and grouping in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following db config:

```
db={
  "order": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "version": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "version": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "version": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "version": 2
    }    
  ],
  "orderDetail": [
    {
      "orderId": 1,
      "orderDate": new Date("2020-01-18T16:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      "orderId": 1,
      "orderDate": new Date("2020-01-11T16:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      "orderId": 1,
      "orderDate": new Date("2020-01-12T16:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the fluent interface to perform a [Lookup](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluentExtensions_Lookup__3.htm) joining the orderDetails to the order collection (as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530363/aggregate-lookup-with-c-sharp)). Now that I have the join in place what's the best method to:

1. Sort the *joined* array such that the details are sorted by orderDate
2. Group the Orders (by OrderID) and sort by version to select the latest (largest Version #)

The workaround I implemented for #1 involves sorting the list after performing the lookup, but that's only because I wasn't able to apply a sort to the "as" of collection as part of the Lookup.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB v3.6 or higher, you can use the $lookup with uncorrelated subqueries to use the inner pipelines to archive what you want.

[Join Conditions and Uncorrelated Sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Since you didn't provide what collections or fields you are using, I will give a generic example:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "orders",
         let: { customer_id: "$_id" },
         pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$customer_id",  "$$customer_id" ] } } },
            { $sort: { orderDate: -1 } }
         ],
         as: "orders"
       }
    }
]);
```

I hope that gives you a way to get where you want. =]