# MongoDb C# Lookup to map value from an other collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to collection, let's say `ColA` and `ColB`:

```cs
public sealed class ColA : IDatabaseObject
{
  [BsonId]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("colb_id")]
  public Guid ColB_Id { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class ColB : IDatabaseObject
{
  [BsonId]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get in a projection `Proj` the result of `ColA` and get the Title of `ColB` through the `ColB_Id` in `ColA`, but I'm not able to do it, there is a way without doing it in 2 separate query ?

```
public sealed class Proj
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid Colb_Id { get; set; }
  public string OtherTitleName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
this.db.GetCollection<ColA>()
  .Aggregate()
  .Lookup<ColA, ColB, Proj>(
    this.db.GetCollection<ColB>(),
    a => a.ColB_Id,
    b => b.Id,
    // I need something like...
    a => new Proj {
      Id = a.Id,
      ColB_Id = a.ColB_Id,
      OtherTitleName = b.Title
    }
  )
```

Is the lookup is the solution or I really need to do it in two steps ?

Comment: You'll need to perform this operation in two steps: first, the $lookup stage to join ColA and ColB, and then a subsequent $project stage to reshape the output as you need it.

Comment: Not sure what to do after the Lookup, maybe Unwind then Project, but I don't know how to chain method to obtain what I need

Comment: first perform the $lookup stage to join ColA and ColB based on the colb_id field and alias it as colBData. Then, in the $project stage, we reshape the output to match the Proj class.While it does involve two stages in the aggregation pipeline, this approach will give you the desired result without the need for two separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pipeline = new[]
{
    // Step 1: Lookup to join ColA and ColB
    new BsonDocument("$lookup",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "from", "ColB" },     // The foreign collection name (ColB)
            { "localField", "colb_id" },  // Field in ColA to match
            { "foreignField", "_id" },   // Field in ColB to match
            { "as", "colBData" }   // Alias for the joined data
        }
    ),
    
    // Step 2: Project the result as needed
    new BsonDocument("$project",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "Id", "$_id" }, // Include the _id from ColA
            { "Colb_Id", "$colb_id" }, // Include the colb_id from ColA
            { "OtherTitleName", "$colBData.title" } // Include the title from ColB
        }
    )
};

var result = this.db.GetCollection<ColA>()
    .Aggregate<Proj>(pipeline)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with your example and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530363/aggregate-lookup-with-c-sharp) I succeed to achieve what I wanted