# C# MongoDb driver include child object

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to Mongo and have a project that uses the [C# MongoDb driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/) and Linq for retrieving data from MongoDb.

I have an object named `Instance` that I retrieve from the Mongo collection just fine. However, the object's `Template` property belongs in a separate collection and is null when querying the Instance collection. I would like to eager load the template data when querying the instance.

This would be the equivalent of Entity Framework's `Include` method which eager loads related entities. I have searched the net for an equivalent approach using the C# Mongo driver but no luck.

How can I accomplish this using the C# MongoDb driver and Linq?

```
public class Instance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var collection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Instance>("Instances").AsQueryable()
var instance = collection.First(i => i.Id == 1);
var template = instance.Template; //always null
```

Comment: How do you retrieve `instances` collection?

Comment: @dododo I've updated the post, I use this to get the collection: `MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Instance>("Instances").AsQueryable()`

Comment: Since `Template` is a separate collection, you need to use `lookup` for your target:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638372/how-to-lookup-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Comment: @dododo Agreed. However, that is projecting to an anonymous type. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/linq/#lookup I need to return the data as the `Instance` type (in this case). I am hoping there is something more flexible that can also be used for other collections of different types (eg. Order => OrderDetail) without manual projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Typed Lookup like this>

```
public class Instance
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjectId TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var instances = db.GetCollection<Instance>("Instances");
var resultOfJoin = instances.Aggregate()
    .Lookup("Templates", "TemplateId", "_id", @as: "Template")
    .Unwind("Template")
    .As<Instance>()
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
Unwind part edited by jcruz.

Comment: this seems promising. For some reason the parameter-less `Aggregate` method only works on `IMongoCollection<T>` and I can't cast from `MongoCollection<T>`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which versions?

Comment: v2.2 https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Aggregate__1.htm

Comment: I figured it out, I was using `MongoServer` instead of `MongoClient`. However, your solution returns an array of Templates where I need a single object (I can't change this) so I get the following error: "Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a Namespace.Template value, but found a value of type Array instead.". Any way to adjust this to return a single Template object?

Comment: I was able to use `Unwind` to get a single Template object returned. I added my edit to your answer. Thank you for the help!!!