# Can not get mongodb Aggregate query result in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, bson

I have create two data models and try to apply different query on it using mongoDb C# driver.
Here is the query in a get method

```
var res = _postCollection.Aggregate().Lookup("_commentCollection", "Comments", "_id", "result").ToList();
return OK(res)
```

But when I call the method from postman get the following result

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
   at get_AsBoolean(Object )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
...............
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is casting! You want to try cast the object type "MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId" to type "MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean". This is not possible and you will receive an exception

Comment: I don't know where MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean come from , I didn't use this type

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for the Lookup are [Ref](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_AggregateFluentBase_1_Lookup__2.htm)

```
string foreignCollectionName,
FieldDefinition<TResult> localField,
FieldDefinition<TForeignDocument> foreignField,
FieldDefinition<TNewResult> as,
AggregateLookupOptions<TForeignDocument, TNewResult> options
```

so the localField and foreignField must be of the same type. In your case they are of different type clearly shown in the error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
   at get_AsBoolean(Object )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
```

Here is the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638372/how-to-lookup-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver?rq=1) on SO which can help you.

Comment: Both was same type, I tested on mongo shell there it worked but not here

Comment: @Hridoy_089 and the type is?

Comment: type BsonObjectId

Comment: @Hridoy_089 the default name for this column is _id have you changed for the second collection?

Comment: I used public ObjectId Id { get; set; } for both collections

Comment: @Hridoy_089 are your sure the type of "Comments"  "_id" are same? You are trying to join two collection and getting the result?

Comment: Comments is list of ids. but I tried with another item string vs string but getting same error

Comment: @Hridoy_089 I would request to see aggrigation pipelie of mongo db and search for lookup. Here is a link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aggregation-pipeline-in-mongodb/   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530363/aggregate-lookup-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the generics to **Lookup()**

```
var res = _postCollection.Aggregate().Lookup<ResultType, Comment>("_commentCollection", "Comments", "_id", "result").ToList();
```